# LinearLayout onClick doesn't work after TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-linearlayout

I have 6 LinearLayouts which are all in `centerVertical` and `centerHorizontal`. And now I want them to move, when the Activity starts, to all corners and sides, each. (In each corner should be one Layout and on the left center and on the right center). I achieve this, for Example, with this TranslateAnimation:

```
 xbox360animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, distanceWidth,
            0.0f, 0.0f);
    xbox360animation.setDuration(1500);
    xbox360animation.setFillAfter(true);
    xbox360Layout.startAnimation(xbox360animation);

    animationxboxone = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -distanceWidth,
            0.0f, 0.0f);
    animationxboxone.setDuration(1500);
    animationxboxone.setFillAfter(true);
    xboxOneLayout.startAnimation(animationxboxone);

    animationps3 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, distanceWidth,
            0.0f, -distanceHeight);
    animationps3.setDuration(1500);
    animationps3.setFillAfter(true);
    ps3Layout.startAnimation(animationps3);

    animationps4 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -distanceWidth,
            0.0f, -distanceHeight);
    animationps4.setDuration(1500);
    animationps4.setFillAfter(true);
    ps4layout.startAnimation(animationps4);

    animationwiiu = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, distanceWidth,
            0.0f, distanceHeight);
    animationwiiu.setDuration(1500);
    animationwiiu.setFillAfter(true);
    wiiuLayout.startAnimation(animationwiiu);

    animationpc = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -distanceWidth, 0.0f, distanceHeight);
    animationpc.setDuration(1500);
    animationpc.setFillAfter(true);
    pcLayout.startAnimation(animationpc);
```

My XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_above="@id/nextBtn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/xboxOneLayout"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/xboxOne"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_background_not_selected"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/xbox"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Xbox One"
            android:id="@+id/xboxOnetv"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/xbox360Layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/xbox360"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_background_not_selected"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/xbox"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Xbox 360"
            android:id="@+id/xbox360tv"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ps3Layout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/ps3"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_background_not_selected"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/playstation"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ps3"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:id="@+id/ps3tv"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ps4Layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/ps4"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_background_not_selected"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/playstation"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ps4"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:id="@+id/ps4tv"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/wiiuLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/wiiu"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_background_not_selected"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/wii"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WiiU"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:id="@+id/wiiutv"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/pcLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/pc"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_background_not_selected"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/desktop"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PC"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/pctv"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't click on them after the animation. When I click on the position where it should be before the Animation, I get the onclick on one of the Layouts.
How can I set the Layouts to the new position, so I receive the onClick Event from the right Layout?

Comment: you can use focuschangelistener or Gesture listener you problem wil be solved

Comment: can you shortly explain how I can use it? Or do you have a link with an example?

Comment: sure i will upload a an example related to this

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: sorry my English is not good If your problem is solved please accept the answer and Up-vote my answer

Comment: with your anser, it is not working... I dont know why

Answer (score 2):

Here i am showing you example of Gesture Listener in Code i have using image View but you can change it into Linear Layout

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private ImageView iv;
   private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   private float scale = 1f;
   private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
   }

   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      SGD.onTouchEvent(ev);
      return true;
   }

   private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
      SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

      @Override
      public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
         scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
         scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));
         matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
         iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TranslateAnimation only moves the pixels on the screen, and does not really move your LinearLayouts, it only makes it look like it is moving, so an OnClickListener will not animate with it. You still should be able to click at the old position before the animation.

Try [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) or [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html).

Example with ViewPropertyAnimator for your xbox 360 layout:

```
xbox360Layout.animate().translationX(distanceWidth).setDuration(1500);
```

Now your layout really moves on the screen and your OnClick should work on the new position.